# Rewrite middle of URL

Tags: asp.net, iis, web-config

Hello I would like to redirect coaches to managers, I have changed the name of the folder and I would like to redirect users to the new correct path instead of them getting 404.

As below

example.co.uk/services/coaches/care/ to be example.co.uk/services/managers/care/

Another example would be redirecting example.co.uk/cars/car-news/vw-gte/ to
eample.co.uk/cars/car-blog/vw-gte/ in the 'car-news' folder there are a lot of cars so I would just like to put in place a redirect so that is rewrites /car-news/ to /car-blog/

Is there a way in the web.config to just redirect "coaches" to go to "managers"?

Comment: Can you not just do a check to see what job role they are and if they are coaches, redirect them to a manager controller?

Comment: It's a folder change all of the same content just the folder is now called managers instead of coaches. If I were to change the folder name and not put redirects in place I will start getting 404 errors in my google analytics and SEO could be affected.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-the-url-rewrite-module It's going to take some time to learn.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use server redirect on HTTP handler